Jaeger with Badger backend - archive storage not initialized
I'm trying to setup Jaeger (v2.1) to use the Badger as a backend storage with enabled archives. I have created my own Jaeger image (due to specific requirements that I need to download the .tar.gz file and build it from there).
To build my custom docker image I have prepared the config-badger.yml according to the docs. Here's the content:
service:
  extensions: [jaeger_storage, jaeger_query, healthcheckv2]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp, jaeger]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [jaeger_storage_exporter]
  telemetry:
    resource:
      service.name: jaeger
    metrics:
      level: detailed
      address: 0.0.0.0:8888
    logs:
      level: info
    # TODO Initialize telemetry tracer once OTEL released new feature.
    # https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/10663

extensions:
  healthcheckv2:
    use_v2: true
    http: # The HTTP health check endpoint (13133)

  jaeger_query:
    storage:
      traces: requests_store
      traces_archive: archive_store
    ui:
      config_file: /etc/jaeger/config-ui.json

  jaeger_storage:
    backends:
      requests_store:
        badger:
          directories:
            keys: "/tmp/jaeger/"
            values: "/tmp/jaeger/"
          ephemeral: false
          consistency: true
          maintenance_interval: 1m0s
      archive_store:
        badger:
          directories:
            keys: "/tmp/jaeger_archive/"
            values: "/tmp/jaeger_archive/"
          ephemeral: false
          consistency: true
          maintenance_interval: 2m0s

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317  # Bind to all network interfaces
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318  # Bind to all network interfaces
  jaeger:
    protocols:
      thrift_compact:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:6831  # Bind to all network interfaces

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  jaeger_storage_exporter:
    trace_storage: requests_store

And the last line from the dockerfile to point to the config is:
CMD ["./jaeger", "--config", "/etc/jaeger/config-badger.yaml"]

I've built the image in a local registry under the name of custom-jaeger:2.1.
Here's my docker-compose-v2.yml (I'm also setting up the HotRod app to send traces to the local jaeger instance):
services:
  jaeger:
    image: custom-jaeger:2.1
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "6831:6831"
      - "4317:4317"
      - "4318:4318"
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug
    networks:
      - jaeger-example

  hotrod:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-}jaegertracing/example-hotrod:${HOTROD_VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8083:8083"
    command: ["all"]
    environment:
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger:4318  # For exporting traces
      - JAEGER_HTTP_HOST=jaeger:16686  # This allows Hot Rod to find traces on the Web UI
    networks:
      - jaeger-example
    depends_on:
      - jaeger

networks:
  jaeger-example:

However, for some reason I always get the error (docker compose -f docker-compose-v2.yml up) :
jaeger-all-in-one-jaeger-1  | 2024-12-09T18:39:46.078Z  info    jaegerquery/server.go:142       Archive storage not initialized {"kind": "extension", "name": "jaeger_query"}

when trying to enable archives.
Other than that- everything is working. I'm able to send the traces using the HotRod app and view them using local instance of Jaeger. However I can't get around fixing the archive part. I've tried using tmpfs and volumes withing the docker-compose, but the error is the same. The example configuration for config-badger.yml suggests it should be supported, but these docs are all over the place and to be honest it's not easy to find the answer I'm looking for.
What am I'm missing?

It's a bug. Please open an issue in Jaeger. From the logs:
Archive storage not supported by the factory
Archive storage not initialized

